# Pass arguments to a view in Drupal 6 via custom module

Tags: drupal-6

I'm using Drupal 6 to run a gallery I've created. I need to take a parameter from the AJAX request lets say "food" and pass that argument to a view I've created (Views 2) where "food" is a taxonomy term that I am using to get the data I want in return. Everything is working just fine and in my module's method for loading the view I can load the entire view because in the settings you have 'if no argument get all values', but I can't seem to pass arguments to it. Here is the method...

```
function ajax_methods_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/settings/ajax_methods'] = array(
        'title' => t('AJAX Methods settings.'),
        'description' => t('Define settings for the AJAX Methods'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('ajax_methods_admin'),
        'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
    );
    $items['gateway'] = array(
        'title' => 'AJAX Gateway',
        'page callback' => 'ajax_methods_get_items',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content')
    );
    return $items;
}

function ajax_methods_get_items($args)
{
    $content = views_get_view('All_Images');
    return drupal_json(array('status' => 0, 'data' => $content->preview('default')));
    exit;
}
```

In looking at the documentation views_get_view() doesn't seem to allow for arguments although I believe they are being passed to my ajax_methods_get_items() method. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Care to show your full source? I'm interested in implementing the same functionality. I have the view taking arguments. I'm after the ajax portion. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, I needed to add

```
return arg(1);
```

seems to be working pretty well.